java.io.IOException: DER length more than 4 bytes
Estoy desarrollando la siguiente clase, consiste en una firma de certificado de tiempo en Base64 del hash SHA-256 de un idAplicacion:
String idAplicacion = "idAplicacion";
        String ficheroCer = "PRUEBAS.cer";
        String ficheroP12 = "PRUEBAS.p12";
        char[] password = "8ba73c7240".toCharArray();
        String selloTiempo = "http://xxxxxx:0000/tspTSA/inputRequestTSA";
        
        //Generar hash SHA-256 del idAplicacion
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            messageDigest.update(idAplicacion.getBytes());
            byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest();           
            String sha256 = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash);
            System.out.println(sha256);
            
            //Cargar el certificado y clave privada
            InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(ficheroP12);
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            ks.load(inStream, password);
            String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, password);
            
            //Generar firmar CADEST-T en Base64
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");
            signature.initSign(privateKey);
            signature.update(hash);
            byte[] signatureBytes = signature.sign();
            System.out.println("longitud: " + signatureBytes.length);
            
            //crear una instancia de la API de firma Stand-alone
            DateStandAlone dsa = new DateStandAlone();          
            byte[] dateCAdES = dsa.dateCAdES(signatureBytes, selloTiempo, false);
            
            String base64Encoded =  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(dateCAdES);
            
            System.out.println("Resultado: " + base64Encoded);
            
        }

Y en la línea byte[] dateCAdES = dsa.dateCAdES(signatureBytes, selloTiempo, false); se produce el siguiente error:

java.io.IOException: DER length more than 4 bytes     at
org.bouncycastle.adapted.asn1.ASN1StreamParser.readLength(ASN1StreamParser.java:60)
at
org.bouncycastle.adapted.asn1.ASN1StreamParser.readObject(ASN1StreamParser.java:151)
at com.openlandsw.dsp.module.motor.cades.q.a(SourceFile:382)    at
com.openlandsw.dsp.module.motor.cades.q.(SourceFile:311)    at
com.openlandsw.dsp.module.motor.cades.b.(SourceFile:570)    at
com.openlandsw.dsp.module.motor.cades.b.(SourceFile:541)    at
com.openlandsw.dsp.module.motor.cades.b.(SourceFile:519)    at
com.openlandsw.dsp.module.motor.cades.b.(SourceFile:479)    at
com.openlandsw.dsp.module.motor.cades.b.(SourceFile:449)    at
com.openlandsw.dsp.module.motor.highlevel.W.a(SourceFile:58)  at
com.openlandsw.dsp.module.standalone.crypto.DateOperatorImpl.a(SourceFile:158)
at
com.openlandsw.dsp.module.standalone.DateStandAlone.dateCAdES(SourceFile:244)
at
paquetePrueba.DateStandAlonePrueba.main(DateStandAlonePrueba.java:60)

Me gustaría saber cómo podría solucionar esto.
Cualquier duda a aclaración, decídmelo y lo reviso.
Muchas gracias.
Un saludo.
